# Not right date is displayed

Tags: javascript, momentjs, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I use this daterangepicker: https://github.com/dangrossman/daterangepicker

I receive a date from database: so the format is: `YYYY-MM-DD`

Web client don't necessary use this format.
I tried that

```
<input type="text" id="samplingsBuildDatePicker" name="receptionDate" class="form-control">

$('#samplingsBuildDatePicker').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true
});    

var dateStart = moment("2018-01-01", 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).format();
$('#samplingsBuildDatePicker').data("daterangepicker").setStartDate(dateStart);
```

Current day is displayed instead of the first day of the year...

Edit

I added a text area

```
$("#remark").val(dateStart);
```

It's the correctly value who is displayed: `01/01/2018`... date picker don't working

Comment: did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here `var dateStart = moment("2018-01-01", 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).format();`

You are receiving date from DB in `YYYY-MM-DD` format and you want to convert to `DD/MM/YYYY`.

Check the below working example for how to do this:

```js
var dateStart = moment("2018-01-01").format("DD/MM/YYYY");

console.log(dateStart);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

So, make the following changes:

```
var dateStart = moment("2018-01-01", 'YYYY-MM-DD', true).format();
```

Change to:

```
var dateStart = moment("2018-01-01").format("DD/MM/YYYY");
```

You are Done!